# Browser refresh shows "page not found" error, when the single-spa application is deployed in the subdirectory

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, single-spa, single-spa-angular

My single-spa contains 4 react applications. Each has its own react-router-dom. If I hit browser refresh from one of the 4 applications it says page not found. Application is deployed in the apache server in Linux OS.

I don't know whether I'm missing any configuration in the base application. It works fine in the development server which is webpack and node.

Comment: Have a look at this answer and the related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40591955/7867822

Comment: Thank you very much. Your suggestion helped me to solve this problem. If anybody wants help with the ".htaccess" file use this link https://docs.bolt.cm/4.0/howto/making-sure-htaccess-works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, because your deployed application is not aware of the routes. In single page applications, only your `/` route exists. All routes in SPAs are client side routes and don't make seperate GET request to the server.

I faced the same issue when deploying my application to netlify. It showed default netlify 404 page. Then I added `_redirects` file to public directory with following contents:

`/*    /index.html   200`

This redirected all 404 routes to default index.html and thus used the client side routing. You need to find something similar for your deployed version.

Comment: Thanks, @Shubham Shinde. If anybody wants help with the ".htaccess" file use this link https://docs.bolt.cm/4.0/howto/making-sure-htaccess-works